# Check a list of checkboxes automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have this list of Checkboxes

[image]

like the select of files with the "Ctrl" Button,I want per example when I check a first checkbox with the press of "Ctrl" Button then check a second checkbox and the "Ctrl" is always pressed ,the other checkboxes between those checkboxes will be checked automatically
with many searches,I found that I should use the "ng-keyup" method
have you please any idea how can I do that??
thanks for help

Comment: I thought it was the SHIFT button that selected all files between the first and last selection. At any rate, we need to see your HTML to help with this.

Comment: Brief solution: When the first checkbox has been clicked with 'Ctrl' pressed, store the array index of the scope element in a separate variable. Then, when clicking again with 'Ctrl', check if this variable is set and then run a loop to select all elements and then clear the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is keep track of all the inputs and the last input clicked.
And then on the next click check if the shift key is pressed and then mark all in between inputs as checked.

```
// last input checked index variable, initialize with null
var lastChecked = null

//keep all inputs saved
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")

// on each click check if shift is pressed
function handleClick(e, index){
  if(e.shiftKey){
    markSelected(lastChecked, index)
  }
}
```

here is an example on codepen that takes care of marking both ways (start to finish and the opposite) and handling the bookkeeping of the last selected input

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEqzWw)